# Regex to find 10+ instances of a character

Tags: regex

I'm trying to figure out how to make a regular expression that will find X instances of a certain character in a paragraph/string. It will include newlines, and the characters are not consecutive. I feel like this should be really simple, but I can't seem to figure it out (and searching the web, I can only seem to find solutions that grab the same character in a row).

Unfortunately, it HAS to be a regex.

Comment: *it HAS to be a regex* who is forcing you...?

Comment: I've tried something along the lines of (.?a.?){10,}, which looks for the letter a appearing 10 to unlimited times. But it doesn't seem to work right, and the . character doesn't include newlines anyway. Most people are looking for the same character in a row, so googling this problem hasn't been fruitiful.

Comment: Try something like this: (?:t(?:.*|\n)?){10,} (assuming T is the character in a row you're looking for)

Comment: with support of inline modifiers and assuming that the character is X: `(?s)^[^X]*(?:X[^X]*){10}`

Comment: Thank you John, this is pretty close. It still doesn't appear to take newlines into account though (at least, regex101 says it doesn't).

Comment: Thank you Sebastian, this is perfect! You're great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your regex-engine of choice supports inline modifiers, you can use

```
(?s)^[^X]*(?:X[^X]*){10}
```

- `(?s)` is a modifier for singleline mode (dot matches newline)
- `^` is the anchor for the start of the string
- `[^X]*` matches anything that is not X, zero to unlimited times
- `(?:X[^X]*){10}` matches X followed by 0 or more not Xs, 10 times

assuming that the character you want is X - u can simpley replace it whatever you like. I used the negated class `[^X]` for performance reasons, as it is faster than either `.*` or `.*?`

See https://regex101.com/r/tW8tH4/1 for a demo.

Comment: Thanks for this. Out of curiosity, is there a way to make it apply to an entire word?

Comment: @AKirby Yes, there is - `(?s)^.*?(?:test.*?){10}` or `(?s)^.*?(?:\btest\b.*?){10}` depending on how you would handle if you want to match `abctestxyz` (first one) or only `abc test xyz` (second one). Please accept my answer if it suits your needs.